# Unable to access values of localStorage.getItem(JSONObj)

Tags: javascript, ajax

### How to access values of localStorage.getItem(JSONObj)

```
var result = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("resultData")); // ---In Ajax SuccessCallBack I have written var parseResult = JSON.stringify(result);localStorage.setItem("resultData",parseResult); --- 

alert("Result :"+result); // I get proper result here
var obj_res = result.getTest_Data; // PHP - $data['getTest_Data'] = $query->result(); ----// tried with result.getTest_Data[0] , result.["getTest_Data"]
//alert(obj_res);// Undefined
$("#txtTTDNo1").val(obj_res.QC_TTDNo1);  // Assigning Value to Text box
```

---

Getting error :

> "Can not read property "QC_TTDNo1" of undefined.

Comment: What does your JSON look like, try doing `console.log(result)`. Make sure it has a `getTest_Data` property.

Comment: Add the value of `localStorage.getItem("resultData")`

Comment: @Spencer Yes it has 'getTest_Data' Property. In alert i can see it. @ Rashmin Where should i add it?

Comment: @Rashmin.. It worked.. could see data in "alert(obj_res);" after adding ValueOf() .. However unable to assign data to $("#txtTTDNo1").val(obj_res.QC_TTDNo1);

Comment: can anyone help on this?

Comment: Resolved. Again i had to parse JSON as I was JSON.stringify() while localStorage.setItem("")...... var data1  = JSON.parse(result);
            var data = data1.getTest_Data;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved. I had to again parse JSON as I was JSON.stringify() while localStorage.setItem("")...... var data1 = JSON.parse(result); var data = data1.getTest_Data;